# Converting a collection.foreach from c# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, subsonic, foreach

In C# i just put the method in the parentheses that i want to run on each row of the collection, but it isn't working in VB.NET.

ex:

```
SubSonic.PartCollection Parts;
...
Parts.ForEach(TestMethod);
```

I've tried this in VB.Net, but it's not compiling, and i'm not quite sure what I'm missing.

```
Dim Parts as SubSonic.PartCollection
...
parts.ForEach(TestMethod)
```

If i break it apart and do it manually it works:

```
for each p as SubSonic.Part in Parts
    TestMethod(p)
next
```

I'm just trying to clean things up a little

Thanks
Tony W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
parts.ForEach(AddressOf TestMethod)
```

In fact the ForEach method accepts a delegate of type Action<T> and you should use the AddressOf to pass a pointer to a given method in VB.NET

Comment: Awesome, that was it

Thanks
Tony W